# Allocate server ports to jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, port

I have several servers run jenkins jobs. To run exclusively, every jenkins job run on one port, such as http://*:13010. To create a new job, now I need check all the jobs in jenkins and name a new job with port, like new_job_13020. But it's not convenient. I want to automatically allocate port to each job. Does anyone know how?

Here is my idea:
1. create a job as template. The job run scripts to query all jenkins jobs' name and get ports used. Then get a unused port on the server and rename the jenkins job;
2. When create a new job, copy the template job in step1 to it.

But here is the problem:
 If create two jobs, this is possible that two jobs get the same ports. Job A allocate port A, before rename the job. Job B allocate port B.

Does anybody have some suggestions?

Comment: I suggest to ask this on superuser.

Comment: Does every job needs to a have it's own Port or just a 'free' port out of a pool of ports? See port allocator plugin - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Port+Allocator+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The plugin don't meet my requirement. And it maybe harder to develop a new plugin than the idea I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late to answer this question, but may be others can benefit from the suggestion. There is a Jenkins plugin `Port Allocator` which solves this problem by letting Jenkins do the book keeping.

You can read more about it [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Port+Allocator+Plugin).

Comment: Looks perfect. But did not work with pipelines :-( There is a PR claiming to make it work, that hasn't been pulled yet: https://github.com/jenkinsci/port-allocator-plugin/pull/10